# operator overloading and template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a template class `template<typename T, typename R>`. R is of type `vector<T*>` or `list<T*>`.

I want my class to overload `[]` operator so that in case it is a vector I will use the built in `[]` operator for efficiency and in case it's a list I will implement it with iterator.

To me it sounds like a job for template specialization so I thought to write something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T& tContainer_t<T, R>::operator[]( unsigned i )
{
    //TODO with iterators   
}

template<>
T& tContainer_t::operator[]<T, std::vector<T*> >( unsigned i )
{
    // TODO with built in [] operator
}
```

This is wrong and the compiler doesn't allow this.

Is there a way to make it work, or should I use `typeid()` to differ the two objects at runtime and act accordingly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it with templates is to make a static helper function in a class that can be partially specialized.  However, what I would do is:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T& tContainer_t<T, R>::operator[]( unsigned i )
{
    //assuming that the container refernce is name container;
    typename R::iterator itr = container.begin();
    std::advance(itr, i);
    return *itr;
}
```

`std::advance` is guaranteed that for a container with random access iterators (such as vector), it is constant time (basically, it does iterator + n), it can be as fast as doing the pointer lookup vector performs.  Otherwise, it does `iterator++` n times, which will be linear time.   The const version will use const_iterator, but is essentially the same.

Doing it this way will let you properly handle different types of containers (not just vector and list), without having to modify the code.

Comment: Think we can agree on the way to answer this.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: I suppose we can :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to overload the operator. The library aleady contains overloaded functions to help you. `std::advance` will move an iterator, taking advantage of `operator+()` for random access iterators.

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T& tContainer_t<T, R>::operator[]( unsigned i )     
{
    typename R::iterator it = myContainer.begin();
    std::advance(it, i);

    return *it;
}
```